# Character matching in R

Tags: regex, r

In R, I have table:

```
Field1

&&hello
&hi
Hello
Hi
```

How to remove everything that starts with "&"?

```
gsub("&", "", A$Field1)
```

will only remove "&" but not "&&hello" or "&hi" as I need it.
I tried "&*" or "&+" but it’s still not working.

Comment: If, as seems to be referenced in the question this is related to a previous question, please edit and add a link that refers to this previous question.

Comment: I added the regex tag, as this (as well as your previous question) will almost certainly simply need the correct regex. But you might want to clarify the exact structure of your data _after_ you've loaded it into R. Data frame? Matrix? Vector?

Comment: To simplify @joran's comment: _What is `table`?_. **R** has `table` class, and frankly, I doubt that this data structure resembles object of `table` class. (take a look at `?table` or `HairEyeColor` which is a dataset that ships with every standard-issue R installation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gsub`, you need to match the whole string:

```
gsub("^&.*", "", A$Field1)
```

but I find a combination of `ifelse` and `grepl` a little more elegant:

```
ifelse(grepl("^&", A$Field1), "", A$Field1)
```

If the goal is to replace it in your dataframe, then you can reassign:

```
A$Field1 <- ifelse(grepl("^&", A$Field1), "", A$Field1)
```

Comment: `^&` should suffice, you don't have to check for one-or-many occurrences of all-but-newline character. `grepl` is faster, and `ifelse` is evil =D (as it will do length coercion on return). I'd rather get a logical vector to apply indexing on desired object... be it a `vector` or `data.frame`.

Comment: @aL3xa, thanks but my answer assumes that `A` is a data.frame and that the user wants to do an in-place replacement of the `Field1` column. With that in mind, the output must be as long in length as `A$Field1` and none of your comment applies.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll try @ work.  Looks exactly what I was looking for. I'll try both gsub and ifelse

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but if you want to remove the lines with an ampersand in them, you could use:

```
a <- c("&hi", "&&hello", "Hello", "Hi")

b <- a[-grep("&", a)]

> b
[1] "Hello" "Hi"
```

Cheers, 
Jim

Comment: `a[!grepl(...)]` would be safer in the event that `a` had no such element matching `&`.

Comment: grapl will remove records. But I needed to leave empty records - to replace && with "" or with " "